# Use Basemap in Alternate CRS Webmap

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap, qgis2web

I am attempting to utilize an OSM basemap for an Arctic-projection web map that views the Earth with the North Pole as the center of the map. Specifically, a North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant is the desired coordinate system for this web map. Is there any way to project the OSM basemap to this coordinate system?

If not, are there alternate basemaps that may work for this purpose? I have attempted the few I've found from ArcGIS servers, but they have resulted in Python errors, stating I am missing a .tif file. I have connected to the basemap properly and am able to view it within QGIS but exporting as a web map results in an error.

The alternate basemap in question: https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Polar/Arctic_Ocean_Base/MapServer/0

The error in question when using qgis2web:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ArcticOceanBase01668794346_piped.tif'`

Comment: I'm not sure if qgis2web and the libraries it is based on support other projections than web mercator - did you check this? In this case, not the basemap as such would be problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might prove difficult to get to work. The first thing to try is use an OSM basemap, export in OpenLayers format (Leaflet 100% will not work), and make sure you select the qgis2web option "Match project CRS". If I'm honest, I can;t remember if that works for basemaps, but it's worth a try.

On the Python error, there's no support in qgis2web for ArcGIS servers, I'm afraid.